# Tiling on horsehair plaster ceiling over shower

Tags: shower, tile, ceiling

I'm tiling over a tub shower in my hundred plus year old house.  I've already replaced lathe and plaster around tub as area with cement board.  Since the ceiling is secure, I would like to apply tiles directly without backer board.  I would also use moisture barrier over everything.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Home Improvement. You told us what you intend to do but what is your question?

Comment: I would guess that the extra weight of the tiles will pull that horsehair plaster from the ceiling lathes...

Comment: Thanks for replies...and to clarify, my question was if this would be a bad idea to skip the backer board.  As mentioned, the ceiling feels fairly solid from what I can tell.  What I was trying to avoid was additional loss of ceiling height in an all ready low ceiling over the tub as I  was originally thinking I'd loose 2 1\4"

Comment: ...of clearance.  I located two joists running parallel to the tub and am thinking I could screw backer board into these if used with construction adhesive.  Otherwise, I can just paint the ceiling.